# Trusted domains in IDsObjectPicker

Tags: windows, active-directory, com

Suppose I have two domains with trusted relationshaip between each other. I initialize `IDsObjectPicker` to select users and I want to see users from both of the domains, but it shows me users only from the domain the local computer is joined to.

I.e. under "Entire directory" in "Location" I see only current domain.

Which scope should I use to display users from all trusted domains?

I have tried to specify `DSOP_SCOPE_TYPE_ENTERPRISE_DOMAIN`, `DSOP_SCOPE_TYPE_GLOBAL_CATALOG`, `DSOP_SCOPE_TYPE_EXTERNAL_UPLEVEL_DOMAIN`, `DSOP_SCOPE_TYPE_EXTERNAL_DOWNLEVEL_DOMAIN`, but it didn't help at all.

Using `DsEnumerateDomainTrusts` with `DS_DOMAIN_DIRECT_INBOUND` flag I can enumerate all trusted domains - it works, but `IDsObjectPicker` doesn't show me them.

Logged on user is a member of the domain the local computer is joined to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved my problem. By some mistical circumstances `DSOP_SCOPE_INIT_INFO` with `fType` set to `DSOP_SCOPE_TYPE_EXTERNAL_UPLEVEL_DOMAIN | DSOP_SCOPE_TYPE_EXTERNAL_DOWNLEVEL_DOMAIN` didn't work properly.
The solution is to use two corresponding `DSOP_SCOPE_INIT_INFO` instances inside of a `DSOP_INIT_INFO`.